# How can I use setString procedure properly?

Tags: java

I have the following situation...

I use CallableStatement from java.sql package. When I use setDate function prior to executing stored procedure, I get an error:

> Cannot find symbol symbol: method
>   setDate(int, java.util.Date) location:
>   interface java.sql.CallableStatement"

Here's the sample code:

```
Connection con = null;
CallableStatement proc_stmt = null;

Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://servername;databaseName=DBName", "UNAME", "PASS");

proc_stmt = con.prepareCall("{ call InsertSomething(?, ?) }");

proc_stmt.setString(1, "A00999999");
proc_stmt.setDate(2, new Date());

proc_stmt.executeQuery();

proc_stmt.close();
con.close();
```

I even tried this using Calendar class with appropriate functions, but the effect was the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be a java.sql.Date, a sub-class of java.util.Date

Comment: You've beaten me by 5 secs :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the java.sql.Date class instead of the java.util.Date class.